# indent output of bash script

Tags: bash, shell, indentation

I am writing a piece of code that has several outputs. The part where I output stuff has two functions, the first of which outputs some indented message. I would like the second function to print something starting from the indentation level of the previous output. So the second function should be aware of the indentation level of the first. How do I achieve this?

```
    outputfunction1
    outputfunction2
```

as opposed to

```
    outputfunction1
outputfunction2
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: You can maintain a global variable to know the current indentation level. For example, in function 1: `INDENT="    "`, and function 2 would use this variable to prepend the indent to each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a fun (but terrible) idea.

```
#!/bin/sh                                                    

function1() { printf '\t\toutputfunction1\n'; }                
function2() { echo bar; }                                      
indent (){                                                     
        indent=$(printf '%s' "$(for ((i=$1; $i>0; i--)); do printf '\t'; done)")                                               
        shift                                                  
        $@ | sed "s/^/$indent/"                                
}                                                              

get_indent() {                                                 
        # Call a function and return the indentation of the last line.
        $@ | awk '1; END{ exit( match($0, "[^\t]") -1 )}'    
}                                                              


get_indent function1                                           
indent $? function2
```

Note that this relies on "indent" being defined as number of hard tabs.  I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to do this for arbitrary whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your function / command using the following `run_indented` function:

```bash
run_indented() {
  local indent=${INDENT:-"    "}
  { "$@" 2> >(sed "s/^/$indent/g" >&2); } | sed "s/^/$indent/g"
}
```

**Example:**

```
foo() {
  echo "foo"
  run_indented bar
}

bar() {
  echo "bar"
}

run_indented bar

run_indented foo
```

**Outputs:**

```
    bar
```

and

```
    foo
        bar
```

As you can the output is properly nested.

There's no need to keep a global indent.

If a functions outputs are modified so that they get prefixed, there is no escape, because everything your indented function calls is going to inherit the file descriptors of your function—and those get indented.

That is, if a function of which the output is already indented, calls another function with `run_indented`, the indentations stack up and create the nested output.

Comment: Suggest `sed "s/^[[:space:]]*/$indent/"` as the regex to handle space or tab replacing *zero-or-more* occurrences of leading whitespace with the specified `$indent`. May also consider nesting functions may be a bit cumbersome depending on the number of different outputs. Maybe a single `print_indented() { ... }` function that each of the output functions could use to provide output thereby providing a consistent manner of indentation rather than nesting individual output functions within one another. May explain why you use `stderr` as the file descriptor also? But good effort.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin **1 whitespacing)** Your regex applies a unifying indent and can't be used to nest. If you try it out, you will get the lines "    bar", "    foo", and "    bar"—each with the same indent.
**2 file descriptors)** There is no universal solution as it depends on the program or shell function of which you want to indent the output. Just the fact that some take the type of file descriptor into account and others don't, should be proof enough. In other words: without a specific use case I can't tell if your proposition is worth considering or not.

Comment: All fair, you already got my vote, so my comment wasn't a criticism. Nested indents is not something you run across every day of the week.